# How to enable the bold font in terminal that's intergrated in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm struggling on how to enable the **bold** text in the integrated terminal that is pre-installed in `Visual Studio Code`.

So far I've tried enabling in the `settings.json` using these parameters:

`"terminal.integrated.enableBold": true` , but had no luck.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Or if there is a more customizable terminal that you happen to know of, I'll be glad to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these to `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontWeight": "normal",
"terminal.integrated.fontWeightBold": "bold",
```

Note: these need to be at the "top level" of `settings.json`. Do not nest them under `"workbench.colorCustomizations":` where you set the terminal colors such as `"terminal.background"`

Supposedly, you could also set a value from 1 to 1000, but that didn't work for me when I tried `1000` or `"1000"` on VS Code 1.62.1 (Oct 2021).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vscode_x64 v1.15.1, and somehow it enabled bold font by default

As I tried switching between bold or not, it just works fine

Comment: I'll see again when `1.15.1` comes out.

Comment: I'm using 1.17.1 on osx and this setting "terminal.integrated.enableBold" isn't recognized.

Comment: well, the same on windows v1.17.1, too. I think it has been removed for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This works..!

```json
"terminal.integrated.fontWeightBold": "100"
```

Just increase the number for Boldness ;)